Can I model the interaction between a continuous variable and two factors separately for each factor?
I'm wondering if I can model the effect of the interaction between a continuous variable and two factors in a model without including the three-way interaction between the two factors. Let's imagine I want to know the effect of the water temperature on activity by a frog depending on its sex and the time of day (night of day). Does the following model make sense statistically speaking ?
$$
Activity = \text{sex} + \text{timeofday} + \text{water_temp} +\text{sex}:\text{water_temp} + \text{timeofday}:\text{water_temp} 
$$
where : represent the effet of the interaction between two variables without their main effet.
I want to know if the effect of the water temperature on the activity depends on the sex and the time of day but I don't need the distinction between male at nigh, females at night, males during the day and females during the day. Just the overall effect of sex and of the time of day. Or do I need two models such as :
$$
Activity = \text{timeofday} + \text{sex}*\text{water_temp} 
$$
and
$$
Activity = \text{sex} + \text{timeofday}*\text{water_temp} 
$$
I don't know why I can't figure this out but any help would be appreciated thanks.

How are you doing this? R, Python, some other statistical package?

You can very well include 2-way interactions without including the 3-way interaction. However, it's generally not a good idea to include the 2-way interactions without the main effects, though it may sometimes be OK. See this discussion for instance.

Hi Dave2e, thanks for your answer. I'm using R and Generalized Additive Models (GAMs) with the gam function from the mgcv package. I used a basic syntax for a linear model because my question was not specific to GAMs.

Hi Sointu, thanks for your answer. Good to know. I was actually planning on including the main effects as well I just didn't want to include each combination of my two factors because it consumes degrees of freedom for something I'm not that interested in. I want to know the effect of sex and the effect of the time of day but not the effect of sex per time of day or time of day per sex.
